# How to make Web RTC work behind Symmetric NAT?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, turn, coturn, xirsys

I've created 2 simple webpages (for peer 1 and peer 2) that exchange a few messages with WebRTC data channel. You need to manually copy-paste offer and answer between the webpages. After the answer is pasted back to peer 1 the connection is established and those messages are sent and received. But, it only works if both peers are behind normal NAT.

Therefore I tried to use TURN server. I tried self-hosted Coturn server and Xirsys turn service, but just couldn't get them to work.

The web pages on codesandbox are:

- Peer 1: https://codesandbox.io/s/web-rtc-peer-1-shared-zl09e
- Peer 2: https://codesandbox.io/s/web-rtc-peer-2-shared-9z40r

The sandboxes now have fake credentials for turn servers, but I used real ones (static) in my experiments.

So, if I use this sandboxes in symetric NAT, or I just force the use of turn server with config `iceTransportPolicy: "relay"`, then it does not work - the connection does not open.

**Question 1:** What do I have to do to make it work?

**Question 2:** Can you make it work with your own TURN server (and `iceTransportPolicy: "relay"` config option?

Comment: did you make it work?